# Completion with cakephp ctp file in PhpStorm

Tags: php, cakephp, autocomplete, phpstorm

it's a bit boring to adding this in each ctp files with phpStorm :

```
/** @var Class $this */
```

I can not find a way to set globally the variable "$this" to the View class in ctp files, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that's not possible (a PHPStorm plugin could of course add that functionality).

You could report this as an enhancement request for the CakePHP bake shell, having this added automatically to the baked view templates wouldn't hurt.

For better cross IDE compatibility it should however probably better be in

```
/* @var $this Type */
```

format.

CakePHP 2.x > **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues**
CakePHP 3.x > **https://github.com/cakephp/bake/issues**